# How to export object list to text ordered by name?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

Alright so blender can output an objectlist with this:

```
`for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:`
 blenderCipher.write('\n'+obj.name+'\n')
```

The issue is the order that blender sets this in. I want it to be based off of the number the object is named to. For example, Model_01, Model_02, Model_03, Model_04, ect.

Blender would instead order it at random like model_05, model_04, model_01, model_03 ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bpy.context.selected_objects` is a list of objects, it is not guaranteed to be in any specific order, to get the list in order you need to sort it yourself.

Python has the builtin function [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort lists. As it can't sort objects directly you need to specify a key function that can provide a sortable key. Using the example from pythons [Sorting How-To](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/sorting.html#operator-module-functions) you can use `attrgetter()` to get the objects `name` attribute to use for sorting.

```
import bpy
from operator import attrgetter

for obj in sorted(bpy.context.selected_objects, key=attrgetter('name')):
    print(obj.name)
```